# Drawing line graph in iOS

Tags: ios

I would like to implement the graph functionality like in the attached image. Can anyone suggest the framework for it.

Right now am using the below code but not able to draw line using x,y axis.
 below is the sample code am using to draw lines, 
     lineChart.addLine(data5) //here data5 is an array contains x-Values dynamically, the y values are static starting from zero. Now I want to make y values also dynamic.

The addLine method calls drawline function as:

```
        func drawLine(lineIndex: Int) {

    var data = self.dataStore[lineIndex]
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    var xValue = self.x.scale(0) + x.axis.inset
    var yValue = self.bounds.height - self.y.scale(data[0]) - y.axis.inset
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: xValue, y: yValue))
    for index in 1..<data.count {
        xValue = self.x.scale(CGFloat(index)) + x.axis.inset
        yValue = self.bounds.height - self.y.scale(data[index]) - y.axis.inset
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: xValue, y: yValue))
    }

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.frame = self.bounds
    layer.path = path.CGPath
    layer.strokeColor = colors[lineIndex].CGColor
    layer.fillColor = nil
    layer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    self.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    // animate line drawing
    if animation.enabled {
        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        anim.duration = animation.duration
        anim.fromValue = 0
        anim.toValue = 1
        layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    }

    // add line layer to store
    lineLayerStore.append(layer)
}
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can refer [this library sample](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/ChartView) for your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) for this. But it is also not that hard to draw such lines yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIBezierPath to draw such chart.Please dive in that class you will find a lot of things to create such line chart.